# Convert SDO_GEOMETRY's sdo_point attribute to text

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, attributes, oracle-spatial

I have SDO_GEOMETRY objects in Oracle 18c:

```
select
    sdo_geometry(2002, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(1, 2, 3, 4)) as shape
from
    dual
union all
select
    sdo_geometry(2001, null, sdo_point_type(-79, 37, null), null, null) as shape
from
    dual

Output:
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2002, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 2, 3, 4))
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(-79, 37, NULL), NULL, NULL)
```

In a query, I want to select the SDO_GEOMETRY's `sdo_point` attribute as literal text (for concatenation purposes).

Example: (fails)

```
select
    'the geometry sdo_point attribute is: ' || a.shape.sdo_point
from
    (
    select
        sdo_geometry(2002, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(1, 2, 3, 4)) as shape
    from
        dual
    union all
    select
        sdo_geometry(2001, null, sdo_point_type(-79, 37, null), null, null) as shape
    from
        dual
    ) a    

--Desired output:
--'the geometry sdo_point attribute is: null'
--'the geometry sdo_point attribute is: (-79, 37, null)'

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 37
```

I don't know how to convert that object attribute to text. I've tried using the SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY() function. But that only seems to work on a point geometry as a whole, not on the specific sdo_point attribute.

---

How can I select the SDO_GEOMETRY's `sdo_point` attribute as text?

Comment: Just a heads up:

DB<>FIDDLE doesn't seem to output objects correctly. It outputs an empty resultset, which can be confusing. [Return a value/row when selecting SDO_GEOMETRY](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=2008)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you specifically need to extract SDO_POINT info. The typical usage of SDO_POINT is to hold coordinates for point geometries (2001, 3001), and in that case, the rest of the SDO_GEOMETRY object is empty.  It is also possible to fill SDO_POINT when the rest of the object contains information, but in that case, the content of SDO_POINT is ignored.  What I mean is that if you deal with points only, and the coordinates are in SDO_POINT then just converting to GeoJSON or WKT or GML should be fine ...

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Fair question. I want to learn about interacting with SDO_GEOMETRY object ***attributes***. Just as a learning exercise...since I don't have much experience with that. So I'm trying to solve a "nice to have" challenge, which is to *output SDO_GEOMETRY properties to text in DB<>FIDDLE* (the same way that SQL Developer does when we hit F5). I talk about it here:  https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16834549/ ...  
 https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=2008.

Comment: Ah OK, I see.  I have a function that does this: it prints out (as text) the content of an SDO_GEOMETRY the same way sqlplus does. Let me pop it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract each `X`, `Y` and `Z` component part of the point and convert those to strings:

```sql
SELECT 'the geometry sdo_point attribute is: '
       || NVL2(
            a.shape.sdo_point,
            '('
            || COALESCE(TO_CHAR(a.shape.sdo_point.X), 'NULL') || ', '
            || COALESCE(TO_CHAR(a.shape.sdo_point.Y), 'NULL') || ', '
            || COALESCE(TO_CHAR(a.shape.sdo_point.Z), 'NULL')
            || ')',
            'NULL'
          ) AS description
FROM   (
  SELECT sdo_geometry(
           2002, null, null,
           sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1),
           sdo_ordinate_array(1, 2, 3, 4)
         ) as shape
  FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sdo_geometry(2001, null, sdo_point_type(-79, 37, null), null, null)
  FROM  DUAL
) a
```

Which outputs:

> | DESCRIPTION |
> | --- |
> | the geometry sdo_point attribute is: NULL |
> | the geometry sdo_point attribute is: (-79, 37, NULL) |

---

On later Oracle versions, you could convert the `SDO_POINT` to JSON and then translate the JSON to your format:

```sql
SELECT 'the geometry sdo_point attribute is: '
       || TRANSLATE(JSON_OBJECT(a.shape.sdo_point), '{}":XYZ', '()')
         AS description
FROM   (
  SELECT sdo_geometry(
           2002, null, null,
           sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1),
           sdo_ordinate_array(1, 2, 3, 4)
         ) as shape
  FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sdo_geometry(2001, null, sdo_point_type(-79, 37, null), null, null)
  FROM  DUAL
) a
```

Which has the similar output to above.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=99b9b190e0bb69dda606742c983a92c9)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I wrote a while ago that writes out the content of an SDO_GEOMETRY type in a text format just like that used by SQLPLUS:

```
create or replace function sdo_format
  (geom sdo_geometry)
  return varchar2
is
  output_string varchar2(32767);
  MAX_LENGTH number := 3980;
begin
  if geom is null then
    return NULL;
  end if;
  -- Initialyze output string
  output_string := 'SDO_GEOMETRY(';
  -- Format SDO_GTYPE
  output_string := output_string || geom.sdo_gtype;
  output_string := output_string || ', ';
  -- Format SDO_SRID
  if geom.sdo_srid is not null then
    output_string := output_string || geom.sdo_srid;
  else
    output_string := output_string || 'NULL';
  end if;
  output_string := output_string || ', ';
  -- Format SDO_POINT
  if geom.sdo_point is not null then
    output_string := output_string || 'SDO_POINT_TYPE(';
    output_string := output_string || geom.sdo_point.x || ', ';
    output_string := output_string || geom.sdo_point.y || ', ';
    if geom.sdo_point.z is not null then
      output_string := output_string || geom.sdo_point.z || ')';
    else
      output_string := output_string || 'NULL)';
    end if;
  else
    output_string := output_string || 'NULL';
  end if;
  output_string := output_string || ', ';
  -- Format SDO_ELEM_INFO
  if geom.sdo_elem_info is not null then
    output_string := output_string || 'SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(';
    if geom.sdo_elem_info.count > 0 then
      for i in geom.sdo_elem_info.first..geom.sdo_elem_info.last loop
        if i > 1 then
          output_string := output_string || ', ';
        end if;
        output_string := output_string || geom.sdo_elem_info(i);
      end loop;
    end if;
    output_string := output_string || ')';
  else
    output_string := output_string || 'NULL';
  end if;
  output_string := output_string || ', ';
  -- Format SDO_ORDINATES
  if geom.sdo_ordinates is not null then
    output_string := output_string || 'SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(';
    if geom.sdo_ordinates.count > 0 then
      for i in geom.sdo_ordinates.first..geom.sdo_ordinates.last loop
        exit when length(output_string) > MAX_LENGTH;
        if i > 1 then
          output_string := output_string || ', ';
        end if;
        output_string := output_string || geom.sdo_ordinates(i);
      end loop;
      if length(output_string) > MAX_LENGTH then
        output_string := output_string || ' <...>';
      end if;
    end if;
    output_string := output_string || ')';
  else
    output_string := output_string || 'NULL';
  end if;
  output_string := output_string || ')';
  -- output_string := output_string || ' [' || length(output_string) || ']';
  -- Done - return formatted string
  return output_string;
end;
```

NOTE: it returns the output as a `VARCHAR2` and has a hard-coded limit to 4000 characters: it writes `<...>` for the ordinates it could not print.

If your database has been set to use long strings, then you can increase that limit to up to 32767 (actually a bit less - say 32760). Or simpler: modify it to use CLOBs. That is an exercise left to the reader.